# Grouping, summing, sorting and selecting within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'State' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
            'County' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
            'Population': [10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 16, 15, 18, 14]})
```

Looking at the two most populous counties for each state, what are the two most populous states (in order of highest population to lowest population)?

I solved it by using a loop, and now I'm trying to get the same result grouping, summing, sorting and selecting.
The following code works, but I'm sure there are many differnt and more elegant way to do it.

```
df.groupby(['State'])['Population'].nlargest(2).groupby(['State']).sum()\
  .sort_values(ascending=False)[:2].to_frame()\
  .reset_index()['State'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't shorten this alittle.

```
df.groupby(['State'])['Population'].nlargest(2)\
  .sum(level=0).sort_values(ascending=False).index[:2].tolist()
```

No need to convert back to dataframe to retreive states, just get the states from the index directly.  Using `sum` with `level` parameter is just short syntax that over groupby again.

Answer (score 0):

```
(df.sort_values('Population', ascending=False) # order by highest population per country 
.groupby('State').head(2) # get two most populous counties per state
 .groupby('State').sum() # get population of two largest counties per state
 .sort_values('Population', ascending = False)[:2] # get top 2 states by population
 .index # get states names
 .tolist() # convert to list
)
```

Here's an alternate way to do it with explanations of each operation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for contributing an answer. Could you separate each method into separate lines? That would make it much easier for new Pandas/Python users to read.